# Combining functions in xpath selector

Tags: html, xpath

I have a selection I want to make in xpath and can't seem to get it right. So I have: `//td[starts-with(@id, '16276688381') and not(ends-with(@id, '_name'))]`

This is the simple html

```
    <td id="16276688381_name">I don't want this</td>
    <td id="16276688381_B3" >What I want</td>
    <td id="16276688381_B4" >More of these...I want them</td>
```

Once I add the and my selection disappears. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Just note, ends with does not work on its own. starts with and contains work though. I am Version 46.0.2490.80 m of chrome

Comment: Your path selects two `td` elements for me in the sample http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVX. Are you sure you are using an XPath 2.0 implementation? `ends-with` is not supported in XPath 1.0, of course you would get an error about an unkown function if you use it with an XPath 1.0 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin points out, XPath 1.0 does not support `ends-with`, but you can simulate it with some string length calculations:

```
//td[starts-with(@id, '16276688381') and 
     not(substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 4) = '_name'))]
```

Comment: Thanks. The starts-with is redundant now which is why I needed to differentiate. Looks like the site has changed now anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

`ends-with` is a function introduced in XPath 2.0 in 2007, browsers unfortunately still only support XPath 1.0 from 1999.